# Can I use JMeter for non-web-app performance metering?

Tags: java, hudson, performance-testing

So, I have a scientific app written in Java that I need to start performance testing. We have CI up and running, so this should be something that I can turn into a CI job and start getting a time history of our performance. But, I'm having trouble identifying libraries that can help me generate the metrics. JMeter looks very interesting and plays well with Hudson, but the documentation focuses on web-app testing. I don't have that. I have a scientific simulation and our goal is to track memory usage, cpu load, etc. Can I use JMeter for that or is it really focused on the web-app market? Any other recommendations for performance testing a simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at the jmeter perfmon plugin here: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon